# Identity server 4 use cookie with pure js client

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, identityserver4

**Background:**

- I'm using angular for front-end
- .Net core for backend API (using microservices architecture)
- Identity server 4 for auth
- **I want to use cookie with pure js based client, is it possible to get cookie while generating token and then return it in API endpoint response?** I can manually set it in browser cookies using [ngx-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie)

**Code:**

IdentityServer project startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddIdentityServer()
   .AddConfigurationStore(options -> options.ConfigureDbContext = /*configuration goes here*/)
   .AddOperationalStore(options -> options.ConfigureDbContext = /*configuration goes here*/)

   services.AddAuthentication("AuthCookie") //if i add this code, it throws exception HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
     .AddCookie("AuthCookie", options =>
     {
        //options.ExpireTimeSpan = ..; don't set time, expire it when browser is closed
     });
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseIdentityServer();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseMvc();
}
```

In loginController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequest request)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var _discoRequest = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest();

    _discoRequest.Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy() { RequireHttps = false, ValidateIssuerName = false };
    _discoRequest.Address = authority;
    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_discoRequest);
    
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
         {
                        Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                        ClientId = clientId,
                        ClientSecret = secret,
                        UserName = request.UserName,
                        Password = request.Password,
                        Scope = scope
         });
    return OK(tokenResponse);
}
```

AdminAPI project startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
          {
              options.Authority = appConfiguration.IdentityServerSettings.Authority;
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              options.ApiName = appConfiguration.IdentityServerSettings.ApiName;
              options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Reference;
              options.ApiSecret = appConfiguration.IdentityServerSettings.ApiSecret;
          }).AddCookie("AuthCookie", options =>
          {
              //options.ExpireTimeSpan = ...;
          });
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In Admincontroller.cs

```
[Route("api/getSites")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSites()
{
  //get and return sites data
}
```

How to generate a cookie and send in API response, and then in `api/getSites` endpoint use that cookie for authentication.

**Update:**
why I need a cookie along with token? The reason is I need to implement logout user on browser close, so the cookie will expire once the browser is closed, and then if user opens the browser again, the cookie authentication will fail.

I can't save the token as a cookie because I have show user a message if he's logged-in in multiple places.

Once the cookie is expired user should be auto loggedout.

I'm not interested in other solutions to expire token on browser close as they don't cover all scenarios.

Comment: If I understand your concern correctly then you don't need to generate a cookie in the API endpoint, just create a token in LoginContoller and return it in response then store that token in a cookie (in the client-side code) and pass that token along with every request.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check. I can't save the token as a cookie because I have show user a message if he's logged-in in multiple places. Once the cookie is expired user should be auto logged out.